# Synonym / Retagging request: [mathjax] and [latex]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request, mathjax, latex

The [latex](/questions/tagged/latex) tag, as it is used on meta.stackexchange.com, seems to actually mean [mathjax](/questions/tagged/mathjax).

Comment: I disagree.  I think retagging is more appropriate.  IMO, a synonym basically means "these mean the same thing" and they aren't.  MathJax uses LaTex notation but doesn't mean they will always be used the same.

Comment: @psibsee2003 I have amended the question to be more of a discussion. Could you convert your comment into an competing answer as a counterproposal?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that [latex](/questions/tagged/latex) be made a synonym, with [mathjax](/questions/tagged/mathjax) as the master.